# Tried to install react-navigation , and it says following. how can i fix these errors ? npm audit fix did not work

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

chamika@chamika-MS-7817:~/Documents/React Native Projects/navi$ npm install react-navigation

npm WARN @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.5 requires a peer of react-native@^0.57 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.15.0 requires a peer of @typescript-eslint/parser@^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@5.1.0 requires a peer of @typescript-eslint/parser@2.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@5.1.0 requires a peer of eslint@6.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-navigation-stack@2.0.10 requires a peer of react-native-safe-area-context@^0.6.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

- react-navigation@4.0.10
  updated 1 package and audited 1858915 packages in 11.492s

35 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 4 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not errors, they are just warnings that you need to install the sub-dependencies of the given package yourself. React Navigation is installed successfully in this case and you can use it fine. You can try doing `npm audit fix` which will try to fix these warnings by installing the dependencies.